# IComparable<T> gives stackoverflow when used for negative numbers?

Tags: c#, generics, stack-overflow, icomparable

This is a weired problem, I have implemented simple quick sort as follows..

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> unsorted = new List<int> { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6, 4, 2 };
        List<int> sorted = quicksort(unsorted);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", sorted));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static List<T> quicksort<T>(List<T> arr) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        List<T> loe = new List<T>(), gt = new List<T>();

        if (arr.Count < 2)
            return arr;

        int pivot = arr.Count / 2;
        T pivot_val = arr[pivot];
        arr.RemoveAt(pivot);

        foreach (T i in arr)
        {
            if (i.CompareTo(pivot_val) <= 0)
                loe.Add(i);
            else
                gt.Add(i);
        }

        List<T> resultSet = new List<T>();
        resultSet.AddRange(quicksort(loe));

        gt.Add(pivot_val);

        resultSet.AddRange(quicksort(gt));
        return resultSet;
    }
```

Output is : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

But When I use any negative number in the unsorted list there is a stackoverflow error,

for example
if List unsorted = new List { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6, 4, 2, **-1** };
Now there is a stackoverflow..

What's going on? Why this is not working ?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that your quicksort algorithm has an error, and stepped through it fully?

Comment: Implementation of this simple algorithm is accurate. There is no error in the implementation.

Comment: The error is in your implementation. Try running the set { 0, -1 }. You'll find that the set reevaluated just before the return is equal to { 0, -1 } each time it recurses into the function. The if statement is `0.CompareTo(-1) = 1` each time, which is correct according to the documentation here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2ky8xsk.aspx

Comment: @Shivraj: Except its not.  Your quicksort algorithm has an error.

Comment: It's not error. if data is like 1,0 then sorting is accurate and output is 0,1, problem occurs when input is like {0, -1} ... this algo is direct implementation from wikipedia.. [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Simple_version)

Comment: @Shivraj I don't know what to tell you then. Good luck.

Comment: @Shivraj - If you got this from Wikipedia you did not transcribe the pseudocode to C# correctly.  Look closer at the part where you concatenate sort(loe), pivot and sort(gt).  Now look at what you are actually doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your algorithm has a bug.  Consider the simplest input list { 1, -1 }.  Let's step through your logic.

1. You first choose a pivot index, Count / 2, which is 1.
2. You then remove the pivot element at index 1 (-1) from the `arr` list.
3. Next you compare each remaining element in the `arr` list (there's just the 1 at index 0) with the pivot.
4. The 1 is greater than the pivot (-1) so you add it to the `gt` list.
5. Next you quicksort the `loe` list, which is empty. That sort returns an empty list, which you add to the result set.
6. You then add the pivot value to the end of the `gt` list, so the `gt` list now looks like this: { 1, -1 }.  **Notice that this is the exact same list as you started with.**
7. You then attempt to quicksort the `gt` list.  Since you are calling the quicksort routine with the same input, the same sequence of steps happens again, until the stack overflows.

It seems the error in your logic is that you blindly add the pivot to the gt list without comparing it to anything.  I'll leave it to you to figure out how to make it work.

Edited to add: I'm assuming this is a homework assignment, but if it's not, I would highly recommend using .NET's built in `Sort()` method on `List<T>`.  It has been highly optimized and heavily tested, and will most likely perform better than anything home-brewed.  Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have a debugger try this...

```
foreach (T i in arr)
        {
            if (i.CompareTo(pivot_val) <= 0)
            {

                loe.Add(i);
                Console.WriteLine("loe.add " + i.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                gt.Add(i);
                Console.WriteLine("gt.add " + i.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Defintely there is a problem with  **if (i.CompareTo(pivot_val) <= 0)** when used with negative number it's stack overflow...